# How can we convert google.protobuf.Timestamp to Ruby DateTime object?

Tags: ruby, time, protocol-buffers, epoch

There aren't much of details for this question, I am getting a kafka event where the time is of type `google.protobuf.Timestamp`. These kafka events are being posted(through HTTP) to my rails app where I need the time to be in datetime format of ruby instead of `google.protobuf.Timestamp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert microseconds to nanos and use `Time.at(seconds, microseconds_with_frac) → time`

```
epoch_micros = timestamp.nanos / 10 ** 6
Time.at(timestamp.seconds, epoch_micros)
```

for reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html

Comment: why do you `/ 10**6`? is it a typo? it should be `/10 ** 3`.

Answer (score 5):

`google-protobuf` gem has classes for well known types, such as `google.protobuf.Timestamp` etc.

You can use `Google::Protobuf::Timestamp.new(data).to_time` to get `Time` from protobuf value in a proper way.

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/f763a2a86084371fd0da95f3eeb879c2ff26b06d/ruby/lib/google/protobuf/well_known_types.rb#L74-L97

example:

```
> require 'google/protobuf/well_known_types'
> data = {:nanos=>801877000, :seconds=>1618811494}
> Google::Protobuf::Timestamp.new(data)
=> <Google::Protobuf::Timestamp: seconds: 1618811494, nanos: 801877000>
> Google::Protobuf::Timestamp.new(data).to_time
=> 2021-04-19 14:51:34.801877 +0900
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a bijection to convert `google.protobuf.Timestamp` to `Time` and vice versa:

```
module ProtobufBijections
  # Converts a Protobuf timestamp to ruby time
  # @param [google.protobuf.Timestamp] protobuf_timestamp
  # @return [Time] Ruby time object
  def to_ruby_time(protobuf_timestamp)
    epoch_micros = protobuf_timestamp.nanos / 1000
    Time.at(protobuf_timestamp.seconds, epoch_micros)
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: for others who don't know what a "bijection" means: 
"... a function between the elements of two sets, where each element of one set is paired with exactly one element of the other set"