# Ruby: Generate Google Protobuf TimeStamp from Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, protocol-buffers

Here is a model `blog`.

```
# id  :bigint(8)
#  created_at                  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at                  :datetime         not null

class Blog < ApplicationRecord

end
```

I would like to convert model's created_at and updated_at to google Protobuf TimeStamp

```
blog = Blog.first
blog.created_at
```

**How to convert DateTime to google Protobuf TimeStamp when forming a protobuf message?**

Comment: Do you have already see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682652/how-can-we-convert-google-protobuf-timestamp-to-ruby-datetime-object ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google protobuf library has methods to do it:

```
require 'google/protobuf/well_known_types'

# Convert ruby Time to protobuf value
time = Time.current
Google::Protobuf::Timestamp.new.from_time(time)

# Convert protobuf value to ruby Time
data = {:nanos=>801877000, :seconds=>1618811494}
Google::Protobuf::Timestamp.new(data).to_time
```

See: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/f763a2a86084371fd0da95f3eeb879c2ff26b06d/ruby/lib/google/protobuf/well_known_types.rb#L74-L97

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ruby On Rails, you can do it in the following way:

```
## Convert Ruby DateTime to Google::Protobuf::Timestamp
time = DateTime.now
seconds = time.to_i
nanos = time.nsec
gpt = Google::Protobuf::Timestamp.new(seconds: seconds, nanos: nanos)


## Convert Google::Protobuf::Timestamp to ruby DateTime
micros = gpt.nanos / 10 ** 3
time2 = Time.at(gpt.seconds, micros)
```

### Reference

1. [ActiveSupport: DateTime#nsec](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-nsec)
2. [Stack Overflow: How can we convert google.protobuf.Timestamp to Ruby DateTime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41682652/how-can-we-convert-google-protobuf-timestamp-to-ruby-datetime-object)